# failed to run custom build command for `yeslogic-fontconfig-sys v3.2.0`

Tags: linux, plot, rust, fedora, rust-cargo

I am trying to learn how to plot in Rust and found a guide that is using plotters (if anyone knows a better plotting library let me know.)

https://plotters-rs.github.io/book/intro/getting_started.html

Anyways, I am on Fedora 37 and running into an issue using the example shown in the Getting started section of this guide.

The code is:

```
/*
Example of plotting in Rust
*/

use plotters::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    
    let root_drawing_area = BitMapBackend::new("0.1.png", (1024, 768))
        .into_drawing_area();

    root_drawing_area.fill(&WHITE).unwrap();

    let mut chart = ChartBuilder::on(&root_drawing_area)
        .build_cartesian_2d(-3.14..3.14, -1.2..1.2)
        .unwrap();

    chart.draw_series(LineSeries::new(
        (-314..314).map(|x| x as f64 / 100.0)
        .map(|x| (x, x.sin())), &RED))
        .unwrap();

}
```

In my cargo.toml file I've added the dependency using `cargo add plotters`

But when I run the code with `cargo build` I get this error:

```
Compiling yeslogic-fontconfig-sys v3.2.0
error: failed to run custom build command for `yeslogic-fontconfig-sys v3.2.0`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/usr/Dev/RustyKrab/plotting/plot_example/target/debug/build/yeslogic-fontconfig-sys-3bf9e95194fbfdbd/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
```

And goes on for stdout

```
--- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=RUST_FONTCONFIG_DLOPEN
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=FONTCONFIG_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=FONTCONFIG_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=FONTCONFIG_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
```

and stderr

```
--- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: "`\"pkg-config\" \"--libs\" \"--cflags\" \"fontconfig\"` did not exit successfully: exit status: 1\nerror: could not find system library 'fontconfig' required by the 'yeslogic-fontconfig-sys' crate\n\n--- stderr\nPackage fontconfig was not found in the pkg-config search path.\nPerhaps you should add the directory containing `fontconfig.pc'\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable\nPackage 'fontconfig', required by 'virtual:world', not found\n"', /home/usr/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/yeslogic-fontconfig-sys-3.2.0/build.rs:8:48
```

With the last line of the error being `` note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace ``. I've tried running `RUST_BACKTRACE=1 alacritty` but simply just doesn't work.

How can I work around this so I can use plotters in Rust?

Note: I've installed fontconfig with `sudo dnf install fontconfig`

Comment: Install `fontconfig-devel`.

Comment: That worked, now I'm getting a bunch of errors about the code. That's progress thanks!

Comment: @JohnKugelman Thanks, I ran into the same issue on linux mint. Do you know what is causing this issue (all my other experience has shown rust to be fantastic at managing dependencies)? and why still hasn't been solved 6 months on

Comment: @JohnKugelman sorry I wrote the first comment before checking your solution worked on linux mint. It doesn't as there is no fontrconfig-devel in the apt package manager. By any chance do you know what the solution would be on mint? Thanks

Comment: @Pioneer_11 A `*-sys` package such as `yeslogic-fontconfig-sys` from the question is usually a thin Rust wrapper around a native C library. Installing C libraries is outside of Rust's purview. You'll usually need to look for a distro-specific way to install the library; or you might need to download the source and build it yourself if there's no prepackaged version for your distro.

Comment: Did you spell it right? It's `fontconfig-devel` not `fontrconfig-devel`.

Comment: ```(base) pioneer_11@xxxxxxx:~$ apt install fontconfig-devel
[sudo] password for xxxxxxxx:                          
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package fontconfig-devel
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@john-kugelman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68587/john-kugelman) answers this in the comments of the question. To resolve my error here I would have to install the development tools for fontconfig using:

```
sudo dnf install fontconfig-devel
```